# Tkinter selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

So I'm writing a simple selenium script to do some actions on the web. The script works great, and out of boredom, I decided to make it have a GUI, as well. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It starts the chrome web driver, but the gui never runs.

```
from tkinter import *
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

root = Tk()


root.geometry('285x179')
root.configure(background='#F0F8FF')
root.title('MC Vote')


pageField=Entry(root)
pageField.place(x=74, y=26)


voteField=Entry(root)
voteField.place(x=75, y=75)


page=pageField.get()
upvoteCSS=voteField.get()
accounts = ['1','2','3','4']

browser.get(page)
browser.maximize_window()


def btnClickFunction():
    for i in accounts:
        upvoteButton = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(upvoteCSS)
        upvoteButton.click()
        browser.get(page)


Button(root, text='Start bot', bg='#F0F8FF', font=('arial', 12, 'normal'), command=btnClickFunction).place(x=99,y=124)

root.mainloop()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Training\accounts.py", line 36, in <module>
    browser.get(page)
```

Comment: Is this all your code? You are missing imports and variable definitions. You should be getting several errors before it even attempts to run.

Comment: error is from selenium , you cannot pass browser.get(page) it should be either html file or url . what is there in page

Comment: I didn't post the entire script as it contains private info. the "page" is supposed to be an input from the text field gui.

Comment: We don't need the entire script. What we need is just enough runnable code to reproduce the problem. See [mcve]. However, the root of the problem is that you're calling `pageField.get()` about a millisecond after you create the entry widget. The user won't have had time to type anything yet.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first check `print(page)` to see what you really have in variable.

Comment: GUI doesn't work like `input()` - when you create `pageField` then it doesn't wait for your text. It only inform `tkinter` what widget it has to display. And when you run `mainloop()` then it creates window and display widgets. So you try to get value from `pageField` even before it displays `pageField` in window. You should use `Button` to run function which gets value from `pageField` after you put text in `pageField` and you press button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GUI` doesn't work like `input()`. When you create `pageField()` then it doesn't wait for your text. It only inform `tkinter` what widget it has to display. And when you run `mainloop()` then it creates window and display widgets. So you try to get value from `pageField` even before it displays `pageField` in window. You have to use `Button` to run function which gets value from `pageField` after you put text in `pageField` and you press button.

Minimal example

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
from selenium import webdriver

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

def btn_click_function():
    page = pageField.get()
    upvote_css = vote_field.get()
    
    browser.get(page)
    browser.maximize_window()
    
    for _ in range(4):
        upvote_button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(upvote_css)
        upvote_button.click()
        browser.get(page)

# --- main --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

root = tk.Tk()

page_field = tk.Entry(root)
page_field.pack()

vote_field = tk.Entry(root)
vote_field.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text='Start bot', command=btn_click_function)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, this is my first time using GUI in Python. Thanks!